# Writing text into a file suddenly stopps

Tags: printwriter

I have a problem with writing text into a file. I use a PrintWriter with the name log and write into the file with log.println(). I create a txt file with the following code:`File fileDirectory = new File(outputFile_full);

PrintWriter log =null ;

```
    File fileDirectory = new File(outputFile_full);
    fileDirectory.mkdir();

    try {
        File logFile = new File(outputFile_full + "/log.txt");

        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        }


         log = new PrintWriter(logFile);
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occurred:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The program terminates without any problems and creates the log file. If you have a look at this txt-file you see that somehow the writing into the file is stopped abruptly. Sometime even within one command (for example the last line of the file is "cu" altough the command ist "log.prinltn("current Time"). Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Maybe it has something to do with the huge number of lines (around 1000 lines)? If I just print the information on the console (by replacing log.println() with System.out.println()) everything is okay and the printling does not stop.